# Shorten string to just a product name

Tags: php, nlp, linguistics

I need some help. I am trying to shorten a full product name from Amazon. For example:

Samsung Galaxy S II Epic Touch 4G Android Phone (Sprint)

Galaxy S II

I want to do this programatically. Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/preg_match I think...

Comment: What's the logic? That is, how are you determining what to keep/remove?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I think that's what he wants us to tell him.  Answer: there is no good answer.  You could build a database of brand names and product names, and try and match them against title, but that alone is a pretty big task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bdares points out what seems to be the easiest way to handle this -- make a big list of all of the product names, then use some sort of text search to find the product name your string contains.

I asked [Given a list of search terms, how can I tell which ones my string contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022062/given-a-list-of-search-terms-how-can-i-tell-which-ones-my-string-contains) since I can't think of a good way to do this at the moment.

EDIT: And I got a [pretty good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10056567/212555).